# Como criar List de uma classe dentro de outra classe e não ser mapeada no Entity Frameworks

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Tenho uma classe chamada **Camara**

```
[Table("Camara")]
public class Camara
{
    [Key]
    public int CamaraId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Tenho a classe chamada **Tipo Lado**

```
[Table("TipoLado")]
public class TipoLado
{
    [Key]
    public int TipoLadoId { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
    [StringLength(50, MinimumLength = 2, ErrorMessage = "O campo {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} e no máximo {1} caracteres.")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
}
```

Quero incluir esta a lista de itens Câmaras para ser visualizada em outra classe chamada Sequencia se não ser mapeada pelo Entity Frameworks.

```
public class Sequencia
    {
        public Sequencia()
        {
            DataAbate = DateTime.Now;            
        }

        [Key]
        public int SequenciaId { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Data do Abate")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        public DateTime DataAbate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lote")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        public int Lote { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Numero Sequencia")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Favor Digitar um {0} maior que zero!")]
        public int NumeroSequencia { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lado A")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public int LadoA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Câmara Lado A")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public int CamaraLadoA { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Lado B")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public int LadoB{ get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Câmara Lado B")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "O Campo {0} é requirido!")]
        [Range(1, double.MaxValue, ErrorMessage = "Selecione o {0} corretamente!")]
        public int CamaraLadoB { get; set; }

        [NotMapped]
        public List<Camara> CamaraList { get; set; }
    }
```

**Retificando a pergunta tenho duas telas Uma que cadastra Câmaras e a outra Tipo**

Na tela de Sequencia escolho a Câmara onde o Lado A ou B esta e o Tipo que é o Lado A e o Lado B é

[image: Tela de cadastro de sequencia]

Index quero que apareça os nomes dos itens selecionados

[image: Tela Index do cadastro de sequencias]

Comment: Por que você precisa que o *EF* não mapeie? pergunto isso pois talvez o que você quer fazer, não seja para ser feito na entidade e sim em um serviço qualquer.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B como você disse Eu quero fazer um serviço qualquer, é que Eu quero que a Sequencia faça include da tabela Câmara na SequenciaController. daria para passar este esquema ?

Comment: Sequencia tem alguma ligação com câmera? Vou te dar uma resposta sobre o que eu acho que você deva fazer pelo que entendi do seu problema. Qualquer coisa vai comentando que melhoro.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B é o seguinte Sequencia tem ligação com Câmara sim, o problema é que na Sequencia tenho dois campos (Lado A) e (Lado B) que são cada um, um DropDownList que mostra o nome da Câmara e que pega de Câmara os seus respectivos ID e agora quero que no Index e no Detail mostre ao invés dos ID mostre os nomes das Câmaras, entendeu ?

Comment: Entendi, veja a minha resposta se te ajuda, e comente para que eu melhore para você, vejo que talvez você precise de uma terceira classe ainda.

Comment: @RodrigoK.B você poderia me passar um contato por e-mail para poder exemplificar esta dúvida melhor, caso não der comente sim ou não blz ? caso negativo deleto esta mensagem blz

Comment: inclua os detalhes em sua pergunta

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74452/discussion-between-cyberlacs-and-rodrigo-k-b).

Comment: @RodrigoK.B retifiquei a pergunta, agora estou explicando melhor minha necessidade.

Answer (score 0):

O Ideal seria você criar uma classe *Manager* para Camera, seria assim.

```
public class Cameras : List<Camera> {
}
```

Você também poderia usar `ICollection<Camara>` mas acredito que tenha que implementar vários métodos que já existem no `List`.

A sua classe `Sequencia`não teria a propriedade

```
public virtual ICollection<Camara> GetCamara { get; set; }
```

No seu controller você instanciaria a classe `Cameras` e usaria ela em qualquer lugar para adicionar um anova camera. Ex:

```
public classe SequenciaController : ApiController {

   public IHttpActionResult Add([FomBody] Sequencia sequencia){
      var cameras = new Cameras();

      cameras.Add(new Camera(){
        Nome = "Camera Teste";
      });
   }
}
```

Neste exemplo suprimir as rotas, se se for o caso posso colocar se precisar.

Para o caso de pegar os nomes, você pode criar um objeto anônimo ou um *DTO*, acho que seria sua única saida. Segue exemplo. Estou considerando que a tabela Sequencia seria sua index. E vou considerar um contexto qualquer.Estou considerando também que você tenha feito o relacionamento do EF com as entidades Camera e Sequencia.

```
var list = seuContexto.Set<Sequencia>()        
    .Where(s = s.SequenciaId.Equals(id))
    .Select(s => new {
       NomeCameraA = s.CameraLadoA.Name
    });
```

o objeto list deverá ser retornado pelo seu controller, O `Select` quem cria seu objeto anônimo, assim você monta um objeto apra sua view, da forma que precisar.

**É extremamente importane que o relacionamento entre `Sequencia` e `Camera` estejam de acordo com as regras do EF**.

Espero que tenha te ajudado, qualquer coisa comente que melhoro.